# C# Reflection Emit Call with parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, func, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

I want to call a function with a parameter with the `reflection.emit` API. In the following is what I have at the moment. But when I run it, it throws the following exception: `System.InvalidProgramException : Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program`. So my question is what I have wrong in my code snippet below? Can someone help me out?

```
public class Test
{

    public void test()
    {
        Func<int, long> realSquareFunc = (val) => val * val;
        Type[] methodArgs = { typeof(int) };

        DynamicMethod squareIt = new DynamicMethod(
            "SquareIt",
            typeof(long),
            methodArgs,
            typeof(Test).Module)
        ;

        ILGenerator il = squareIt.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Save parameter on stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, realSquareFunc.Method); // Call function with input as parameter
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Return value from function call before

        var myMethod = (Func<int, long>)squareIt.CreateDelegate(realSquareFunc.GetType());
        var result = myMethod.Invoke(4); // Should be 16 (4*4)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work as is if the called method was a static method:

```
public static long RealSquare(int val) => val * val;

public void test()
{
    Func<int, long> realSquareFunc = RealSquare;
    // ...
```

However, the `realSquareFunc = (val) => val * val` lambda is actually compiled as an instance method of a hidden class. To call an instance method, the instance must be pushed onto the stack first, before the method arguments. Instance method calls also typically use the `Callvirt` opcode (regardless of whether they're virtual, because this opcode does null reference checking):

```
public class Test
{
    public long RealSquare(int val) => val * val;

    public void test()
    {
        Func<int, long> realSquareFunc = RealSquare;
        // pass the instance we want to call the method on in as well
        Type[] methodArgs = { typeof(Test), typeof(int) };

        DynamicMethod squareIt = new DynamicMethod(
            "SquareIt",
            typeof(long),
            methodArgs,
            typeof(Test).Module)
        ;

        ILGenerator il = squareIt.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Push the target instance onto stack      
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Save parameter on stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, realSquareFunc.Method); // Call function with input as parameter
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Return value from function call before

        var myMethod = (Func<Test, int, long>)squareIt.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Test, int, long>));
        var result = myMethod.Invoke(this, 4); // Should be 16 (4*4)
    }  
}
```

Calling the target method of a lambda *directly* is more complicated due to the compiler-generated class involved, but if you want to call a delegate in general it works like this:

```
public class Test
{        
    public void test()
    {
        Func<int, long> realSquareFunc = (val) => val * val;
        // pass the delegate we want to call into the method
        Type[] methodArgs = { realSquareFunc.GetType(), typeof(int) };

        DynamicMethod squareIt = new DynamicMethod(
            "SquareIt",
            typeof(long),
            methodArgs,
            typeof(Test).Module)
        ;

        ILGenerator il = squareIt.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Push the delegate onto stack        
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Save parameter on stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, realSquareFunc.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")); // Invoke delegate
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Return value from function call before

        var myMethod = (Func<Func<int, long>, int, long>)squareIt
            .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Func<int, long>, int, long>));
        var result = myMethod.Invoke(realSquareFunc, 4); // Should be 16 (4*4)
    }  
}
```